# power distribution on a 6 wheel drive train

Tags: java, robotics

I'm on a FIRST Robotics Competition team and we're looking into a 6 wheel drive train  for the upcoming season. We're going to use arcade drive with a basic wheel type, like kit of parts. I'm just wondering what other FRC teams have done in the past and what the power distribution looked like.

Answer (score 0):

Team 10874 here.

So my team uses a 2 wheel drive but it basically goes like this : Our right motor's power is negated if it comes from the stick because using the gamepad sends negative values, while our left motor's power is kept positive. For distribution of power, we ask ourselves a question; What direction should the robot drive? If straight, then the integer literal in each power function should be set to 1. If reverse, the opposite (-1). Now my team had a specific question when we switched from Blockly to Java. How does a DC Motor rotate..? It usually only goes straight and backwards. The way you do it is this : If you have two wheel drive (like my team did for the majority of our time), one motor's power should be set to 1 while the other motor's power is set to negative one. Assuming the first motor is the left motor, and the second is the right try to visualize this, the left motor is going straight and the right motor is going in reverse. This will cause the robot to turn to the left! Here is some code

```
private void turn()
    leftFrontMotor.setPower(1);
    leftBackMotor.setPower(1);
    rightFrontMotor.setPower(-1);
    rightBackMotor.setPower(-1);
```